# I am not able to save a data frame to a .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

```
submission=pd.DataFrame({"image_name":ID,'label':predictions.tolist()})
submission.to_csv(submission,index=False,encoding="utf-8")
```

It gives the following error

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Comment: You're supposed to pass a file path not the df: `submission.to_csv(file_path,index=False,encoding="utf-8")` where `file_path` is some path please read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)

Comment: change `submission.to_csv(submission,index=False,encoding="utf-8")` to `submission.to_csv("/path/of/your/output.csv",index=False,encoding="utf-8")`

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
submission=pd.DataFrame({"image_name":ID,'label':predictions.tolist()})
submission.to_csv("submission.csv",index=False,encoding="utf-8")
```